# Existe-t-il un mot pour désigner une personne qui fait hériter quelqu'un ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Un héritier est une personne qui touche l'héritage d'une personne après sa mort, mais est-ce qu'il existe un mot pour désigner la relation inverse ?

Y a-t-il un mot pour désigner la personne de qui on va hériter ? En particulier si par exemple la personne lègue tout ou une partie de son héritage à une personne qui n'est pas de sa famille.

S'il est différent, y a-t-il un mot pour désigner l'émetteur d'un héritage symbolique ? (En parlant d'un groupe par exemple, s'ils sont "les héritiers des Stones", que sont les Stones par rapport à ce groupe ?)

Comment: Il existe le terme juridique *testataire* qui est en est proche : c'est la personne qui lègue par testament. Mais si le legs se fait sans testament, le terme ne s'applique pas.

Comment: @Améraldor: quel est le point que vous désiriez que je clarifie ?

Comment: Avant de lire les réponses et commentaires, j'aurais plutôt dit que *testataire* était plus courant que *testateur*, mais c'était peut-être simplement une fausse impression de ma part, rien de plus. N'étant pas notaire, ce ne sont pas de termes que j'utilise tous les jours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le cas d'un don manuel ou notarié, on utilise les termes

- **donateur** pour la personne qui donne à autrui.
- **donataire** pour la personne qui reçoit le don.

Pour un legs par voie testamentaire, le terme **légateur** pourrait faire le pendant du **légataire**, personne qui reçoit le legs, mais ce terme n'est pas utilisé.  Le **testateur** étant nécessairement la personne qui lègue, on pourrait éventuellement utiliser ce terme sans ambiguïté, mais ce n'est pas tout à fait la réponse à la question.

Depuis quelques jours, on appelle *la personne qui fait hériter ses enfants au détriment des autres* la **marâtre**, mais c'est une autre histoire.

Comment: @Améraldor: vous avez raison, le *testataire* était un lapsus claviaturae et j'ai reformulé la phrase pour éviter l'ambiguïté.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a le mot « testateur » pour la personne qui a fait le testament.

Answer (score 1):

On a le mot Légateur pour celui qui fait un legs à ses légataires. Mais c'est peu usité.

Answer (score 1):

Pour ajouter aux termes suffixés en *-eur* dont on a traité ailleurs, on pourrait utiliser l'*auteur* dans le sens de la « personne de qui une autre (l'ayant cause) tient un droit ou une obligation » ([Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/auteur/6555?q=auteur#6532), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17583977), [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auteur)<sup>1</sup>). Le testateur est donc autant l'auteur du testament le cas échéant (il en est l'origine, voire le créateur s'il est manuscrit) que de ses legs. Le terme *auteur* participe à mon avis à plusieurs niveaux du lexique et des abstractions associées à la matrice de transmission de droits et d'obligations qu'on veut voir ici dans la succession...

---

Pour ce qui est de l'[*héritier*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9ritier) dans le sens de la « personne qui perpétue l'œuvre d'une autre personne, les traditions, les idées des générations précédentes; qui se situe dans la même filiation spirituelle qu'une autre personne » (TLFi), bien cette autre personne pourrait être désignée de *prédécesseur* ([Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h%C3%A9ritier/39679?q=h%C3%A9ritier#39601)) ou de [*précurseur*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pr%C3%A9curseur/63388), par exemple.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> À mon humble avis le TLF inverse cette réalité quand il affirme à *auteur* « Celui ou celle qui tient d'une autre personne (dite ayant-cause) un droit, un privilège, une obligation » (I A 3.).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Pour ce qui est de la dernière partie de la question, pour un usage au figuré concernant par exemple la musique ou la culture au sens large, on utilise souvent l'expression "père spirituel" / "mère spirituelle".